Why am I seeing my requests in network tab of devtools when I'm using Nuxtjs (SSR)
I am using nuxt 3.11.1 and when I am trying to send my requests from the server side I'm yet seeing the requests in network tab which made me doubt if I am sending them correctly or not.
I have written a composable for sending my requests which is like this:
export async function useData(endpoint, params, method = "POST") {
  const authToken = useCookie("Authorization-Token");

  const options = {
    method,
    headers: {
      "Client-Token": import.meta.env.VITE_API_CLIENT_TOKEN,
      "Authorization-Token": authToken.value,
    },
  };

  if (method === "POST") {
    options.body = { ...params };
  }

  try {
    const response = await $fetch(
      `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL}/v1/${endpoint}`,
      options
    );

    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}


And in my page components I try to use this composable as the following:
const authToken = useCookie("Authorization-Token");

if (authToken.value) {
  await useAsyncData(async () => {
    fetchData();
  });
}

async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const response = await useData("URL");
  }

if the authToken does not exist I create my token and send my requests from the client side, but I also store the token in the cookies and will use it for the future requests.
everything is working fine, but I'm seeing all of my requests in the network tab.
I also can not see the data in the payload tab of nuxt devtools
Update:
I changed the useData composable to use useFetch instead of $fetch and now I see any request but the first one and I also can see the requests in the payload tab of nuxt devtools.
here is the updated version of useData:
export async function useData(endpoint, params, method = "POST") {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const authToken = useCookie("Authorization-Token");

    const options = {
      method,
      headers: {
        "Client-Token": import.meta.env.VITE_API_CLIENT_TOKEN,
        "Authorization-Token": authToken.value,
      },
    };

    if (method === "POST") {
      options.body = { ...params };
    }

    const {
      data: { value: response },
      error,
    } = await useFetch(
      `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL}/v1/${endpoint}`,
      options
    );

    if (error.value) {
      reject({
        response: {
          _data: {
            code: error.value?.cause.response.status,
          },
        },
      });
    }

    resolve(response);
  });
}



Not directly relevant but fetchData needs to be awaited

Thanks to @Estus Flask and @Oleksandr,
After updating useData composable and changing $fetch to useFetch I changed
if (authToken.value) {
  await useAsyncData(async () => {
    fetchData();
  });
}

to
await useAsyncData(async () => {
  if (authToken.value) {
    await fetchData();
  }
});

And now I only see the requests after navigating to a page.
Yet I don't know why this fixed my problem but now I can be sure that the requests are being sent from the server side.

In the first snippet, the check if (authToken.value) is made outside of useAsyncData, which leads to the condition being evaluated client-side. As a result, the request is made client-side if the condition is true, causing it to appear in the browser's network tab.

You run your check on client-side. Try this
useAsyncData(async () => {
  if (authToken.value) {
    fetchData();
  }
});


Still able to see the requests in the network tab @Oleksandr

Nuxt's specific composables for data fetching, such as useFetch, useAsyncData, and $fetch, are designed to handle both server and client environments effectively. They prevent redundant network calls by sharing fetched data between server and client, improving performance. Additionally, these composables integrate seamlessly with Vue's , enhancing the user experience by managing async data and state transitions smoothly. Using these composables ensures efficient, SSR-friendly data fetching and better overall application performance.
For more detailed information, you can visit the:
Nuxt documentation
